# Unable to install sasl on MAC

Tags: python, sasl, pyhive

In order to connect to Hive data warehouse from python.
Using pyhive requires sasl - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sasl'

Installing sasl fails with errors below

Python 3.9.4
installed gcc, libsasl2

MACOS Mojave v 10.14

pip3 install sasl

```
   Collecting sasl
  Using cached sasl-0.2.1.tar.gz (30 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sasl) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: sasl
  Building wheel for sasl (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7l/zbp16k6s11v5rypxj86mq_z00000gn/T/pip-install-3a1mge3r/sasl_ebeeb9cd2f6b4067a93195d45bbf68c1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7l/zbp16k6s11v5rypxj86mq_z00000gn/T/pip-install-3a1mge3r/sasl_ebeeb9cd2f6b4067a93195d45bbf68c1/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/7l/zbp16k6s11v5rypxj86mq_z00000gn/T/pip-wheel-r3vsh0mm
       cwd: /private/var/folders/7l/zbp16k6s11v5rypxj86mq_z00000gn/T/pip-install-3a1mge3r/sasl_ebeeb9cd2f6b4067a93195d45bbf68c1/
  Complete output (333 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  copying sasl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  running egg_info
  writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to sasl.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  copying sasl/saslwrapper.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  copying sasl/saslwrapper.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  running build_ext
  building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Isasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.9/sasl/saslwrapper.o
  In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:
  sasl/saslwrapper.h:36:35: warning: 'sasl_dispose' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          ~ClientImpl() { if (conn) sasl_dispose(&conn); conn = 0; }
                                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sasl/sasl.h:746:18: note: 'sasl_dispose' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  LIBSASL_API void sasl_dispose(sasl_conn_t **pconn) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0,__MAC_10_11,__IPHONE_NA,__IPHONE_NA);
                   ^
  In file included from sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:254:
  sasl/saslwrapper.h:179:18: warning: 'sasl_client_init' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          result = sasl_client_init(0);
....
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't support Python3.9 yet
Python 3.7 works
Thank you for your attention folks :)